# Laravel 8 not running tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

First of all, my current environment:

- Docker version 20.10.1
- docker-compose version 1.27.4
- MySql 8.0.21 (Docker Image)
- PHP 7.4.13 - Docker Image
- PHP 7.4.13 Local

Composer.json:

```json
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.0",
    "laravel-lang/lang": "~8.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^4.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.9",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/breeze": "^1.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
}
```

I'm receiving the following errors when running:

- > $ php artisan test

```sh
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: 
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable. 
in /home/______/proj/php//______/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1038
```

My Test file(I didn't even finished writing my test):

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Pessoa;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class __________ extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    protected Pessoa $pessoa;
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->pessoa = factory(Pessoa::class);

        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "solution" was kinda of easy, before searching a lot, I found the following statement on [GitHub issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28809#issuecomment-668553246):

- "For me it turned out to be access rights. This might be an issue for vm/container environments."

I tried running it with SU, and got another error:

- > $ sudo php artisan test

```sh
   FAIL  Tests\Unit\____________
  ⨯ example

  ---

  • Tests\Unit\_____________ > example
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   0.12s
```

Well, and it didn't work either, but because I was using docker to run this project locally, I tried to run it inside the Container, and it worked!

- $ docker exec f546517976f4 php artisan test

*TL;DR : Run the tests inside the Docker Container*